How do I tell Cargo to update dependencies beyond the current versions of my project?
I have a simple project that relies on pyo3. Currently/previously, it was using version 0.20.0, but recently a new version has landed which is version 0.21.2. I am looking for a Cargo command that will update the dependency, even if that then means I have to go back through the source and fix any breaking changes that were introduced. However, if I run:
> cargo update pyo3 --precise 0.21.2

Or just equally:
cargo update pyo3

Then I am met with the following error:
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `pyo3 = "^0.20.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.21.2
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `eight-ball v0.1.0 (/home/harry/Documents/eight-ball)`
perhaps a crate was updated and forgotten to be re-vendored?

Here is the Cargo.toml file as it was before the update:
[package]
name = "eight-ball"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[lib]
name = "eight_ball"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
itertools = "0.12.1"
pyo3 = "0.20.0"

If I go to the Cargo.toml file and manually change the version on pyo3 to the latest version and then build, everything works fine. It doesn't seem like what I am looking for is something crazy, so I feel like I am just using Cargo wrong.
What I wanted was to just be able to run a Cargo command to update me to version 0.21.2, but the obvious choice didn't work, and I couldn't see a --force option or similar. I don't know why it thought that I was so set on remaining at version 0.20.0.
How can I use cargo to update the dependencies on my project without having to modify the Cargo.toml directly?

Not exactly what you're asking for, but the Cargo book suggests using Cargo.lock to specify precise versions and just having general dependencies in Cargo.toml.  The .lock file is what cargo is manipulating. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-toml-vs-cargo-lock.html

This confuses me a bit because at the top of Cargo.lock it always says it's not for manual editing. What I wanted was a Cargo command that was basically just going to jump my dependency to the latest version; I couldn't understand why it refused to do that and what this refusal was based on.

Note that 0.20.x to 0.21.x, like a major version change, is allowed to add breaking changes, so it may break existing code. That's the reason why a cargo update doesn't update it.

You can install cargo-edit:
cargo install cargo-edit

This will add an upgrade command to Cargo. You can use it to:

check for newer incompatible versions:
> cargo upgrade -i --dry-run
    Checking mycrate's dependencies
name old req compatible latest new req
==== ======= ========== ====== =======
pyo3 0.20.3  0.20.3     0.21.2 0.21.2 


update a dependency to latest incompatible version:
> cargo upgrade -i -p pyo3


update a dependency to a specific incompatible version:
> cargo upgrade -i -p pyo3@0.21.2



For background, cargo-edit previously had cargo add and cargo rm that were eventually implemented in Cargo directly. This too may eventually be built-in but related issues indicate uncertainty about how that'd eventually work.

You can now also use the --breaking flag in the default cargo update.
This is currently unstable, so the entire command is:
cargo update --breaking -Z unstable-options
(This appears to be one of multiple advancements in the cargo-edit above that have been rolled into the default cargo update. [cargo remove being another])

cargo 1.77.1: error: unexpected argument '--breaking' found

The full command line if nightly isn't your default is actually cargo +nightly update --breaking -Z unstable-options -- can't wait for this to become stable, subscribed to https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/12425
